# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined despite check for undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing some code to generate JSX based on items in an array, however I'm getting the error 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' despite having checks in place to see whether the variable is actually undefined. The code is really long so I've summarised the problem here:

```
render() {
    var metadata = this.props.data["metadata"]

    if(typeof metadata !== undefined && metadata.length !== undefined) {

        for(var i=0; i<metadata.length; i++) {
            console.log(metadata[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

The render method is inside a component, which is placed inside another, by doing

```
<Marksheet data={this.state.data} />
```

I've checked to make sure that data is actually defined and being supplied as a prop, but even if it was undefined, I don't understand why it's saying cannot read property length of undefined.

Comment: `!== 'undefined'` -> `!== undefined`

Comment: You have a space in `metadata .length`, just before the dot ... was that a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: also, can be simplified to `if (metadata && metadata.length) { ... }`

Comment: @LGSon A space matter so long as it actually is a space. If it's a weird unicode character then that is a problem.

Comment: @ic3b3rg I'd be careful with that. You don't know the OPs intention. A valsey value is not the same as undefined.

Comment: Changing it to underfined instead of 'undefined' seems to still cause the same error. Also checked with null. Yes the space is a mistake with copying, it's not there in the actual code.

Comment: @LGSon Spaces before a dot, while possibly unintentional, won't have any effect on the code

Comment: @CharlieFish ok, can *probably* be simplified to ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the `Array.isArray` method:

```
render() {
    var metadata = this.props.data["metadata"];
    if(Array.isArray(metadata)) {
      metadata.forEach(val => console.log(val));
    }
}
```

Comment: This conditional check is simple and short. No need to bother about whether it is undefined or null. Array.isArray is enough to do conditional check so +1 upvote for you

Comment: I've just tried isArray. Strangely it's still coming up with the same error. I tried if(Array.isArray(metadata)) {
        console.log("it's an array!")
        console.log("the length is: " + metadata.length)
which prints out the length correctly, but the javascript console still says unable to read property length of undefined, and the app crashes :(

Comment: That error cannot come from that code, you have somewhere else some error prone code. Maybe in componentDidMount?

Comment: You're right. Looks like another part of the code was giving the same error

Answer (score 2):

The string `"undefined"` is not the same as `undefined`.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
render() {
    var metadata = this.props.data["metadata"]

    if(metadata !== undefined && metadata.length !== undefined) {
        for(var i=0; i<metadata.length; i++) {
            console.log(metadata[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

That basically checks to ensure both `metadata` and `metadata.length` are not equal to undefined before running that for loop.

Comment: Thank's for the quick reply! I've changed it to underfined instead of 'undefined' but I'm still getting the same error. Also checked with null

Comment: @RayA. Of course! Can you try printing what `metadata` is equal to?

Comment: Doing  console.log("Metadata: " + metadata) prints out "Metadata: Student name, task_id,..."

Comment: @RayA. So then `metadata` is defined looks like. Are you sure the error you posted is correct and is happening where you say it's happening?

Comment: I've double checked the error. This is what comes up in the javascript console:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ProxyComponent.render ...
    The above error occurred in the <Marksheet> component: in Marksheet (at Interaction.jsx:579)

Comment: @RayA. And which line is 579?

Comment: Line 579 is <Marksheet data={this.state.data} />

Comment: Oh, I interpreted that as, the error occurred when creating the component Marksheet, but in the code for Marksheet metadata.length is being read. Which is what I find strange, because .length is read after checking that it's not undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185857/discussion-between-charlie-fish-and-ray-a).

Answer (score 1):

Or just simply. You might also check for `metadata.length >0 (instead of just length)`

```
render() {
    var metadata = this.props.data["metadata"]

    if(metadata && metadata.length) {

        for(var i=0; i<metadata.length; i++) {
            console.log(metadata[i]);
        }

    }

}
```